# MinGW - Header incomplete <netfw.h>

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, firewall

i am developing a networked application in **C++** that should be able to add a rule to the windows firewall. I am following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/c-adding-a-service-rule) using the **MingW g++ compiler**.
The other examples are working without a problem, but this particular example won't work.

The exact problem i am facing, that `NetFwRule` is not defined in the `<netfw.h>` header provided by MinGW. When i try to compile that example with MSVC (in Visual Studio) it works flawlessly, since `NetFwRule` is defined in the header provided by MSVS. However it is absolutely neccessary for the project to use the MinGW g++ compiler.

This particular code snippet as shown in the example link won't work, since `NetFwRule` is not defined:

```
// Create a new Firewall Rule object.
hr = CoCreateInstance(
       __uuidof(NetFwRule), // <- Problem in MinGW g++, but in MSVC it just works
       NULL,
       CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
       __uuidof(INetFwRule),
       (void**)&pFwRule
);
```

So what needs to be done in order to make this work using MinGW?

FYI: I have MinGW 32 bit with posix thread for the i686 architecture installed.

`g++ --version` gives `g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

The error message is: `'NetFwRule' was not declared in this scope`

In fact it really is not declared, since the <netfw.h> of MinGW does not declare NetFwRule. MSVC however does.

Comment: The error message is: 'NetFwRule' was not declared in this scope
In fact it really is not declared, since the <netfw.h> of MinGW does not declare NetFwRule. MSVC however does.

```g++ --version``` gives ```g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0```

Comment: Just tried with `g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0`, the code compiles fine.

Comment: The 32-bit version of MinGW comes with ancient SDK headers. Get the 64-bit version instead that ships with newer SDK headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GCC was too old.

You can get a newer version via MSYS' pacman, or download a standalone build, for example from http://winlibs.com/ which will work just as well if you don't need MSYS2.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I have tried to use MinGW 64 bit just as IInspectable suggested, but that does not work either - the netfw.h header still does not provide NetFwRule. However i have installed g++ along with MSYS2 (the version that rustyx is using), which just works as expected. So if anyone faces the same issue I would suggest to use MinGW along with MSYS2 and not standalone.

Comment: You don't actually need 64-bit per se, but rather MinGW-w64 (which also exists in 32-bit) instead of classic MinGW.